# AspectJ works with Java 7?

Tags: java, eclipse, aspectj

I instaled AspectJ in Eclipse (AJDT), but the specific methods of Java 7 are marked as errors when I use the AspectJ project.

My doubt is if AspectJ works with Java 7 or this is an issue with Eclipse or AJDT.

**EDIT:** The problem is AJDT that doesn't support AspectJ for Java 7 yet. There is some IDE to AspectJ that supports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need AspectJ 1.7.0 M1 (or higher) for Java 7 compatibility. http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/README-170.html

Comment: Also, check if JDT Weaving had indexed all your methods. Sometimes is not dynamic and you have to do it manually. Go to Preferences > JDT Weaving > Reindex now, and restart the IDE. If you don't have that, go to [link](https://www.eclipse.org/ajdt/downloads/) and install the latest AJDT version for your IDE (here you have a very good step-by-step tutorial: [link](https://o7planning.org/en/10257/java-aspect-oriented-programming-tutorial-with-aspectj#a27090))

Answer (score 0):

From the [aspectJ webpage](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/):

"AspectJ 1.7.0.M1 is now available for download. See the readme for more information. **This is our first Java7 compiler based milestone.**" so it should work. Did you search at all?

Comment: Yes, but he is also interested in AJDT, not just the core AspectJ library.

Answer (score 0):

You should install the snapshot version of the AspectJ Development Tools (AJDT) from this update site:

http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ajdt/37/dev/update